# Magento Product Page - Related Product like custom tab

Tags: magento, product, backend

On product page there is a tab called "related products"
I need to create a custom tab like "related blog posts" when blog posts are just products in another category.

So the functionality is pretty much the same as on the "related products" tab, may be I just need to limit the search to specific category.

My question is: what is the right way to create such "custom" tab with functionality similar to Related Products?

Thanks.

Comment: it cant be answered in single line or 2 to 3 steps.. There is lot to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-accessories.html). It adds a new tab called 'Accessories' that works the same way as related products. You can just change the label to 'Blog posts'.